# Execute NOP the command line

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there any command/application, that could be called from command line and has three features:

1. does nothing
2. can be executed silently without any window
3. return 0 at the end.

????

Comment: Just write your own program that does the three things above. That's what StackOverflow is about: Writing programs.

Comment: Thanks for advise, but I can't add any new files to the installation. On the other hand, this command line must be executed after uninstallation of the the product.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like `cmd /d/c rem`. It appears to work even as just `cmd /d/c` on my system, though I'm not sure that's as likely to continue working the same. Both appear to leave `%errorlevel%` as 0.

Your question looks very [XY-like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/312062), though. This is a very odd requirement, and there's likely a way to accomplish what you're actually looking for without executing a program that does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Well, i've found solution by myself - execution of the RUNDLL32.EXE without any parameters gives the required effect.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `rundll32.exe` will return 0 in the future.